# How use asp.net get video duration

Tags: asp.net, get, video-encoding, duration

```
using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback;

Video vvideo = new Video(FileUpload.FileName.ToString());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(duration.toString());
error message;
```

“Installed an access attempt was made to the application domain.”

“vvideo” instance is created error msj ://

But down found cods    I found a working code in c #. but asp.net does not work

```
string file1 = "c://ds.mpeg"
IMediaPosition m_objMediaPosition = null;
FilgraphManager m_objFilterGraph = new FilgraphManager();
m_objFilterGraph.RenderFile(filename);
m_objMediaPosition = m_objFilterGraph as IMediaPosition;

int s = (int)m_objMediaPosition.Duration;
int h = s / 3600;
int m = (s - (h * 3600)) / 60;
s = s - (h * 3600 + m * 60);
```

I DON'T TAKE VIDEO DURATION BOYS :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make Function everywhere it uses ;)

```cs
public string f_VideoDuration((add path)parameters)
{

    try
    {
        string sInputVideo = Page.MapPath(add path);
        string sPath = " -i " + sInputVideo ;

        Process ffmepg = new Process();
        ffmepg.StartInfo.FileName = (Server.MapPath("ffmpeg.exe"));
        ffmepg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ffmepg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        ffmepg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        ffmepg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ffmepg.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        ffmepg.StartInfo.Arguments = sPath;
        ffmepg.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        ffmepg.Start();
        string sDuration = ffmepg.StandardError.ReadToEnd().ToString();
        ffmepg.Close();
        ffmepg.Dispose();

        sDuration = sDuration.Remove(0, sDuration.LastIndexOf("Duration: ") + 10);
        sDuration = sDuration.Substring(0, sDuration.IndexOf(","));
        return sDuration;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does in your answers.

Answer (score 1):

First, I try FFMPEG Wrapper but it gets an error after found an easy solution.

You can use this nugget package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell -Version 1.1.0
```

In your project add two namespaces

> using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell; 
>   using.Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem;

```
ShellFile so = ShellFile.FromFilePath("your file path");
double.TryParse(so.Properties.System.Media.Duration.Value.ToString(), out var nanoseconds);

if (nanoseconds > 0)
{
     double seconds = Convert100NanosecondsToMilliseconds(nanoseconds) / 1000;
     int ttl_seconds = Convert.ToInt32(seconds);
     TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ttl_seconds);
} 

public static double Convert100NanosecondsToMilliseconds(double nanoseconds)
{           
     return nanoseconds * 0.0001;
}
```

Here i store seconds in **TimeSpan** so its directly give hours:minutes:seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use our wrapper for ffprobe [Alturos.VideoInfo](https://github.com/AlturosDestinations/Alturos.VideoInfo).
You can use it simply by installing the `nuget` package. Also the [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) binary is required.

```
PM> install-package Alturos.VideoInfo
```

**Example**

```cs
var videoFilePath = "myVideo.mp4";

var videoAnalyer = new VideoAnalyzer("ffprobe.exe");
var analyzeResult = videoAnalyer.GetVideoInfo(videoFilePath);

var duration = analyzeResult.VideoInfo.Format.Duration;
```